# Error when trying to display the number of pages in PdfKit

Tags: python, qt, python-pdfkit

A few days ago, I started working with PDFKIT, to generate reports in Python.  My problem appears when I want to show the number of pages that the document has. I do not know what I am missing, or where I am failing. Below is the error that is shown, the code that I am using, and the resulting pdf.

```
Error: The switch --footer-right, is not support using unpatched qt, and will be ignored
```

Code:

```
import pdfkit

options = {
    'page-size': 'Letter',
    'margin-top': '1cm',
    'margin-right': '1cm',
    'margin-bottom': '1cm',
    'margin-left': '1cm',
    '--footer-right': '[page]',
}
body = u"""
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta name="pdfkit-page-size" content="Letter"/>
            <meta name="pdfkit-orientation" content="Portrait"/>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <style>
                .td_left{
                    text-align: left;
                }
                .td_rigth{
                    text-align: right;
                }
                img{
                    width: 150px;
                    height: auto;
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 0;
                    left: 0;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <img src='/home/produccion/Downloads/logo.png'>
            <center>
                <h2><b>NOMBRE DE LA EMPRESA - NOMBRE DE LA SUCURSAL</b></h2>
                <h3><b>NIT: 000.000.000-0</b></h3>
                <h2><b>CONTABILIZACIÓN</b></h2>
            <center>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <th>CUENTA PUC</th>
                    <th>BOD</th>
                    <th class='td_left'>TERCERO</th>
                    <th class='td_rigth'>DOC N°</th>
                    <th class='td_rigth'>VENCE</th>
                    <th class='td_rigth'>CANTIDAD</th>
                    <th class='td_rigth'>DÉBITO</th>
                    <th class='td_rigth'>CRÉDITO</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
    """
for i in range(15):
    body += """<tr>
                    <td>0000-00-000</td>
                    <td>{0}</td>
                    <td class='td_left'>NOMBRE DEL TERCERO</td>
                    <td class='td_rigth'>AAA0000000001</td>
                    <td class='td_rigth'>01/01/2000</td>
                    <td class='td_rigth'>0.0</td>
                    <td class='td_rigth'>00000000</td>
                    <td class='td_rigth'>00000000</td>
                </tr>""".format(i+1)
body += """</tbody>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>"""
pdfkit.from_string(body, 'ejemplo.pdf', options=options)
```

Result:

[image: image of the report]

Comment: in the following link, you will find the answer / _en el siguiente enlace encontraran la respuesta_:  [see answer - ver respuesta](https://discuss.erpnext.com/t/wkhtmltopdf-error-erpnext-v7/14673/13)

Comment: Well, since I did not find someone who could answer my question, and after a few hours and hours of research, I found the solution to this inconvenience that I was presenting, the first thing was to have knowledge of the version of wkhtmltopdf that I had installed, in my case it was: "0.12.4" which did not have the (patched qt), so my solution was to return to the version "wkhtmltopdf 0.12.3 (with patched qt)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the installed version of wkhtmltopdf was 0.12.4, which did not have the patched qt. The solution was to uninstall this version and install version 0.12.3 (which does have the patched qt):

```
cd ~
wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.3/wkhtmltox-0.12.3_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz
tar vxf wkhtmltox-0.12.3_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz 
cp wkhtmltox/bin/wk* /usr/local/bin/
```

And this can be confirmed with:

```
$ wkhtmltopdf --version
wkhtmltopdf 0.12.3 (with patched qt)
```